# Save data from SharePoint Online to SQL Table

Tags: sharepoint-online, sql-server, sql-query

I have created one html "User Detail" Form.

Using content editor web part, add this form into SharePoint page(web part page / wiki page).

"User Detail" form contain Button(Save/Submit) for store data.

On Button click i want to save all data into SQL table not in SharePoint list.

Is it possible or have any other solution ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has provided one service called [Power Automate](https://flow.microsoft.com) where you can create flows for automation.

You can achieve your requirement with below steps:

1. Create a flow with "When a HTTP request is received" trigger so you can call your flow from AJAX request.
2. In flow, using SQL server action, you can add data in SQL table.
3. Write button click event in your content editor web part with JavaScript code to call a flow using AJAX request. Pass your data in JSON format in this request.

References:
https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/call-flow-restapi/

Hope this will help you!